# React Native How to open a folder?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, filesystems

I got a URI of directory using [react-native-document-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker#documentpickerpickdirectory) .

```js
let selected = await DocumentPicker.pickDirectory().catch(ex => {});
if (selected && selected.uri) {
    // do something, eg: save a file to the folder.
    // then open the folder
}
```

My question is, how can I open this folder?